# not able to connect to bigcommerce api

Tags: php, bigcommerce

i am facing a problem while i am trying to connect to my bigcommerce account through the bigcommerce api....
i followed the following guidelines according to this url:

1. i downloaded the bigcommerce.php file from here
   https://raw.github.com/bigcommerce/bigcommerce-api-php/master/bigcommerce.php
2. then included this file into my index.php file
3. then i tried to execute the following code in my index.php file

   ```
    require 'bigcommerce.php';
       use Bigcommerce\Api\Client as Bigcommerce;
   ```

   Bigcommerce::configure(array(
       'store_url' => 'storeurl',
       'username' => 'admin',
       'api_key' => '4581223546f2bf73840d84b4802cab039f249404'
       ));

   ```
   Bigcommerce::setCipher('RC4-SHA');
   ```

   Bigcommerce::verifyPeer(false);

   $products = Bigcommerce::getProducts();

   foreach($products as $product) {
       echo $product->name;
       echo $product->price;
   }

but this did not worked for me. it was showing following warning

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp\www\bigcommerce\index.php on line 16

then i followed following steps:

1. i downloaded the ZIP file for the api from here https://github.com/bigcommerce/bigcommerce-api-php/archive/master.zip
2. extrated that file into my project folder say myfolder i.e directory for extracted file is myfolder/bigcommerce-api-php-master/
3. then i included the myfolder/bigcommerce-api-php-master/bigcommerce.php

and tried to execute following code....

```
<?php
 require 'bigcommerce-api-php-master/bigcommerce.php';
    use Bigcommerce\Api\Client as Bigcommerce;

    Bigcommerce::configure(array(
    'store_url' => 'https://store-atka90u.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/',
    'username' => 'admin',
    'api_key' => '4581223546f2bf73840d84b4802cab039f249404'
    ));

    Bigcommerce::setCipher('RC4-SHA');
Bigcommerce::verifyPeer(false);

$products = Bigcommerce::getProducts();

foreach($products as $product) {
    echo $product->name;
    echo $product->price;
}
?>
```

but its showing again the same warning even after i added 2 products already in my account.

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp\www\bigcommerce\index.php on line 16

any kind of help will be appriciated.....
plzzzz help.... it is badly needed....

Answer (score 4):

So, that is because you have the full URL in the path.
Change it to something like the following -

```
Bigcommerce::configure(array(

'store_url' => 'https://store-atka90u.mybigcommerce.com/',
'username' => 'admin',
'api_key' => '4581223546f2bf73840d84b4802cab039f249404'
));
```

Comment: thanx a lot brother.....!!!!!
u saved me from a big problem....
can u also tell me if there is anyway to check whether these credentials(i.e. store_url, username, api_key) are valid or not....
i mean to say how can we check if this information is correct or not....
and one more question to ask that is the store_url in bigcommerce is unique or not....
please reply if u are having any solution for that....
waiting for your reply.....

Comment: @saran you can do a lightweight API call like `Store`, if you get proper reply then this credentials are valid else BigCommerce will throw invalid credentials error.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php
// provision for laziness
if( 
    (array_key_exists('store_url', (array)$settings)) &&
    (array_key_exists('username', $settings)) && 
    (array_key_exists('api_key', $settings)) 
) {
    // Config Basic
    BC::configure(
        array(
            'store_url' => $settings['store_url'],
            'username'  => $settings['username'],
            'api_key'   => $settings['api_key']
        )
    );

    // Set Cipher if needed
    if(array_key_exists('cipher',$settings)) {
        BC::setCipher('RC4-SHA');
    } else {
        BC::verifyPeer(false);
    }

    // Set Proxy if needed
    if(array_key_exists('proxy',$settings)) {
        BC::useProxy($settings['proxy']['url'], $settings['proxy']['port']);
    }
}
// Run your code here...
```

obviously you need to configure the $settings array to include at least the store_url, api_key and username ...